# How to scrape information from another site?

Tags: web, web-scraping, automation, scrape

My idea is to create a website where users would find information from different sites they are registered to. That information would be scraped into our database from those sites when they provide login credentials.  The whole idea is to ease them access to what they want in one place/spot and that would be our site.

Probably the best way for something like this would be using selenium framework or some similar web automatization tool, but since I have no programming background I'm open to all suggestions and advises.

Do you think it's possible to do that and can that be done through the web app (from our own server) or users would still need to install some sort of desktop app? The only reason I can think off to do the scraping part from a desktop is that some sites could possibly block it if a lot of traffic comes from a single IP address.

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a couple of ways for going about what you've described so I'll go through the two I think would work best for your scenario

---

**Selenium**

So you mentioned selenium above which is definitely a good, reliable web automation framework, however in order to use it for multiple sites you may run into a slight issue of having to add a specific method with different locators for each individual site for both logging in, navigating and parsing the site for information.

E.g. For one website your selenium code may be

```
public void LoginSiteA(){
FirefoxDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver();
fd.get(SiteUrlA);
WebElement Username = fd.findElement(By.Id("Unique-ID-1"));
WebElement Password = fd.findElement(By.ID("Unique-ID-2"));
//Set Text on WebElements and submit
}
```

And this would work rather well, unfortunately the "Unique-Id" locators for identifying each element could (and most likely will) vary between websites and you'd have to have a separate set of locators for each website you wanted to support which would get messy quite quickly. Which brings me to my second method

---

**Downloading the raw HTML source**

A second option for scraping a page could be downloading the HTML source directly from the site and this would work well as:

- You could do authentication via the http request
- It would be very generic across multiple websites as no locators are needed
- It would typically be faster than selenium as it does not need to render a webpage

The way you could go about doing it in Java could be like this

So first of all if the site needs to be logged in you will need to handle authentication, I recommend checking out this site [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html) for a crash course at least for NTLM authentication, however each site may differ in authentication methods and you may need to add support for each authentication protocol as you encounter them.

Using the code below you can then pass in a username and password and a URL, and hopefully if all works well you can then get the raw HTML source of the site and parse it for whatever needs you want.

```
static final String kuser = "username"; // your account name
    static final String kpass = password; // retrieve password for your account 

    static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            // I haven't checked getRequestingScheme() here, since for NTLM
            // and Negotiate, the usrname and password are all the same.
            System.err.println("Feeding username and password for " + getRequestingScheme());
            return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
        URL url = new URL(args[0]);
        InputStream ins = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        String str;
        while((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
```

As for the concerns regarding the large amount of traffic coming from a single source, you could either contact the sites you will be hitting with your service to see if 1) they are okay with it and 2) potentially able to whitelist your service's IP for a larger bandwidth amount, as you said it would be possible for the service to run on your clients' machines however this may cause additional difficulty.

If there is anything else I can help with please let me know :)

-James